# 'mixed' and 'lmer' in R provide different estimates for variable coefficients

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models, r-package

I was fitting mixed-effects models in a longitudinal dataset and noticed that specifying the same structure led to different outputs depending on if I used 'mixed' (from package afex) or lme4. I have provided reproducible code below (R version 4.2.2)

```
library(lme4)
library(afex)
library(tidyverse)
library(effectsize)
# Pull in toy data and convert vars to factors
dset_test1 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car_id = row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
  mutate(vs = as.factor(vs)) %>% 
  mutate(am = as.factor(am))

# Create simulated longitudinal dataset
increase_longitudinal <- mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(am, wt) %>% 
  mutate(car_id = row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
  mutate(wt2 = (wt)*2)

# Merge and make long form
dset_test = merge(dset_test1, increase_longitudinal, on='car_id') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(wt, wt2), names_to = 'year', values_to = 'weight') %>% 
  mutate(year = as.factor(year))

# Set reference levels
dset_test$year <- relevel(dset_test$year, "wt")

# fit model with mixed
mix1 <- mixed(mpg~year * weight + hp +(1 | car_id), data=dset_test) 
summary(mix1)
parameters::standardize_parameters(mix1)

# fit model with lme4
lmer1 <- lmer(mpg~year * weight + hp +(1 | car_id), data=dset_test) 
summary(lmer1)
parameters::standardize_parameters(lmer1)
```

This produces the following standardized output:

```
# model with mixed:
Parameter    | Std. Coef. |         95% CI
------------------------------------------
(Intercept)  |      -0.29 | [-0.40, -0.18]
year1        |      -0.81 | [-0.98, -0.63]
weight       |      -1.12 | [-1.36, -0.88]
hp           |      -0.39 | [-0.53, -0.25]
year1:weight |      -0.37 | [-0.45, -0.29]

# Model with lme4:
Parameter      | Std. Coef. |         95% CI
--------------------------------------------
(Intercept)    |      -1.05 | [-1.29, -0.81]
yearwt2        |       1.54 | [ 1.21,  1.86]
weight         |      -1.42 | [-1.72, -1.12]
hp             |      -0.40 | [-0.54, -0.26]
yearwt2:weight |       0.71 | [ 0.56,  0.86]
```

As you can see, the model coefficients are quite different, particularly for the interaction term, where the sign of the coefficient even is different. Thanks for any insight into what might be going on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`afex::mixed()` automatically uses sum-to-zero contrasts by default, since these often make it easier to interpret main effects in models with interactions (but R's default is to use *treatment* contrasts).

If you set `options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))` before running the `lmer()` fit, you'll get identical coefficients. (There are other ways to set contrasts but this is probably the simplest.)

I hope by the way that this is not representative of your real data -- I got **lots** of warnings when I ran this code, and lots of red flags in the output (e.g. the residual standard error was very close to zero, as was the raw `yearwt2` estimate in the original `lmer` fit). If you can it's generally best to generate more sensible test data so that people (like me) don't get distracted/think the problem might be some unidentifiability issue ...

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply! This is incredibly helpful. Would you recommend one contrast method over the other when the interaction is the primary effect of interest (i.e., not main effects)?

Comment: I believe the p-value of the interaction will be the same for either set of contrasts. Note that the overall model fit (including predictions etc.) will be the same whichever contrasts you use; the only question is in the *interpretation* of the parameter estimates.